# Burninate [groups] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/groups) tag does not denote any meaningful single topic. It is being used by 400+ questions for many different topics and has only 3 followers. I suggest burnination.

Comment: Appears to be useless.

Comment: Instead of burning (just removing) the tag, the questions should be retagged with an appropriate [`group …` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tagfilter=group)

Comment: Also to burn - [tag:group] and [tag:grouping].

Comment: Related burninate request -- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286996/add-group-to-the-group-of-tags-to-clean-up-and-burn