# Add [group] to the group of tags to clean up and burn

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Looking at [group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/group), it is obvious this tag is of no use.

The first page contains questions on:

- Unix user groups
- SQL `group by`
- Unix groups in SQL databases (isn't that meta?)
- Python, PHP
- NoSQL aggregation (Mongo DB, XQuery, ...)
- Active Directory
- regular expressions
- Facebook groups
- Joomla
- radio buttons
- and finally a [completely unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075689/angularjs-ngoptions-how-to-order-by-group-name-and-then-by-label) tagged [group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/group)

I guess, this tag would even be a candidate to earn the [Generalist badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist).

Burn it, and burn it hot.

Comment: However, there is the html group tag, <g>,  in SVG. Isn't this a straightforward case where to use the group-tag? Other html tags seem also to be used by their full name.